# Is there a way to find out what was updated with the update query?

Tags: mysql, sql, .net

If I have 3 columns and my program can update all 3 i'll have an update query:

```
 Update table set col1 = @value1, col2 = @value2, col3 = @value3
```

aside from storing all old values to variables then comparing them to the values in the tables once the update is committed, is there anyway to find out what changed and maybe, what didn't?

Comment: What do you mean by "find out"? What do you want to do?

Comment: Well I'm trying to create a log for my program, if I have let's say a form that adds new/update data on a table with customers information, if the user inserts a new info i'll log it as a "new data", if they updated an old info i want to log that as "update data" along with what was change like maybe they changed the customers name or address or phone number etc

Comment: @CodeCaster currently i'm just inserting information i need to a table, like the users log in username, computer name, local ip, just stuff like that

Comment: Then you can do so in a trigger like @Manu suggested. Let the trigger insert changed data in your log table. Whether that's maintainable is a different question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a trigger (after or before) and do what you need in it. If you need that data at application level, this would not work unless storing the old values.

Answer (score 0):

You can have history table with trigger set on main table on update to insert old values to history table before updating it.